# Numerical Analysis Exam

Tags: numerical-methods

We have an upcoming exam and the question I have attached was from last years exam. But I am really stuck on how to get started with it. I would really appreciate some help with it.[image: Exam Question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
$$
\|\delta x\|=\|A^{-1}Aδx\|\le\|A^{-1}\|·\|Aδx\|
$$
and insert the equation, guided by the expected result.